# SQL update the table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to update SQL that INSERT it like this

```
   $save= "INSERT INTO meeting_rooms_calendar(title,body,start,end) VALUES ('$title','$body','$start','$end')";
```

i tried

```
$edit = "UPDATE meeting_rooms_calender SET `start` = '$start', `end` = '$end', `title` = '$title' WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
```

I want to make a editable function so you can change the text and when you hit EDIT it must update the old text in the database

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: It wont update the existing

Comment: You really need to give us more information.  Obviously you're not just using SQL and you haven't mentioned which DB you're using.  What is the structure (datatypes), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in table name. Change

```
UPDATE meeting_rooms_calender ...
                           ^
```

to

```
UPDATE meeting_rooms_calendar ...
                           ^
```

**On a side note:** consider to learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) either with `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of interpolating query strings.

Comment: You're quite welcome. It happens to the best of us :). What you should really be worried about is leaving your code vulnerable to sql injections. That being said, seriously, start using prepared statements. It will make your life and code better in an order of magnitude.

Comment: Im not so good with sql so i dont know how to block sql injections